# Using Excel, how can I control a web page that is already open?

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I have an app that scrapes data from an HTTPS web site.  I am using Selenium software.  My app gets a list of SKU numbers from one page.  It has to go to another page to get a location for each of the SKUs in the list.  For each SKU is has to log into the web site, input the SKU number on the second page.  A list appears with all of the locations of the product with said SKU number.  My application searches this list to find the first location with enough product to fill the order.  If an order has 20 items on it, the program has to log into the second page 20 times and run the process.  For 20 items, it takes over 10 minutes to run.  Is there any way for me to use the already-opened page for all of the items?

This is the function that I have.  I have tried putting the SKU input into a FOR-NEXT loop, but that did not work.

```
Private Function GetProductLocation(SKU As String, QtyOrdered As Integer) As clsLineItem
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim elem As WebElement
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim barcode As String
Dim table As Selenium.WebElement
Dim userID As String
Dim userPword As String

    bot.Start "edge"
    bot.Wait 2000
    bot.Get "https://app.shiphero.com/dashboard/product-locations?warehouses=7145&customer=4222"
    bot.Wait 2000
    
    userID = Application.InputBox("Enter User ID")
    userPword = Application.InputBox("Enter your Password")
    
    bot.FindElementByName("email", 1000).SendKeys (userID)
    bot.FindElementByName("password", 1000).SendKeys (userPword)
    bot.FindElementByName("password", 100).SendKeys (keys.Enter)
    
    bot.Wait 5000

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'SEARCH FOR SKU
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='search_exact_match_product_locations']").Click
    bot.Wait 2000
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='product_locations_filter']/label/input[1]").SendKeys (SKU)
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='product_locations_filter']/label/input[1]").SendKeys (keys.Enter)
    bot.Wait 5000

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'CREATE TABLE
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Set table = bot.FindElementById("product_locations")
    
    Dim AllRows As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim SingleRow As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim AllRowCells As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim SingleCell As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RowNum As Long
    Dim ColNum As Long
    
    Dim LocationIsValid As Boolean
    Dim Enough As Boolean
    Dim Expired As Boolean
    Dim productLocation As clsProductLocation
    Dim lineItem As clsLineItem
    Set AllRows = table.FindElementsByTag("tr")
        Set productLocation = New clsProductLocation
        Set lineItem = New clsLineItem
        
        For Each SingleRow In AllRows
            
            LocationIsValid = False
            Enough = False
            Expired = True
            
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
            Set AllRowCells = SingleRow.FindElementsByTag("td")
    
            If AllRowCells.Count = 0 Then
                Set AllRowCells = SingleRow.FindElementsByTag("th")
            End If
    
            For Each SingleCell In AllRowCells
                
                 ColNum = ColNum + 1
                 
                 Select Case ColNum
                    Case 5 'location
                        If ValidLocation(SingleCell.Text) Then
                            LocationIsValid = True
                            productLocation.Location = SingleCell.Text
                        End If
                        
                    Case 9 'qty available
                        If LocationIsValid Then
                            If CSng(SingleCell.TextAsNumber) >= QtyOrdered Then
                                productLocation.QtyAvailable = SingleCell.TextAsNumber
                                Enough = True
                            End If
                        End If
                        
                    Case 12 'Lot ID
                        If LocationIsValid Then
                            productLocation.LotCode = SingleCell.Text
                        End If
                    
                    Case 15 'days until expired
                        If LocationIsValid Then
                            If CSng(SingleCell.TextAsNumber) >= 285 Then
                                productLocation.DaysUntilExpired = SingleCell.TextAsNumber
                                Expired = False
                            Else
                                Expired = True
                            End If
                            
                            
                        End If
                        
                 End Select
                 
                 If LocationIsValid And Enough And Not Expired Then
                    lineItem.LocationID = productLocation.Location
                    
                    If productLocation.QtyAvailable > 0 Then
                        lineItem.QtyAvailable = productLocation.QtyAvailable
                    End If
                    
                    lineItem.LotID = productLocation.LotCode
                    
                    Set GetProductLocation = lineItem
                    Exit Function
                 End If
    
                
            Next SingleCell
                ColNum = 0
        Next SingleRow
        
        If Enough Then
            lineItem.LocationID = "OOS-EXP"
        Else
            lineItem.LocationID = "OOS"
        End If
        
        Set GetProductLocation = lineItem

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider storing that window handle and then switching back to it if you need. [An example](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#switching-windows-or-tabs) from Selenium official site may inspire you, but it works for newer versions of Selenium.

If you are using the native Selenium Type library which seems to be a much older version, you can try something like

```
bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
```

Comment: Thank you, Kendrick.  Unfortunately, the native Selenium Type library is the only one that  I can find that I can use with Excel (VBA) .  I'll try this and see if I can get it to work.